splines: uniform knot positions
Suppose we have 8 uniformly distributed interpolation points
x = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

and want to define a bspline curve of order k=5, hence the knot vector has 8+5=13 elements.
Typically, the first and last knot are repeated k-times, hence a knot vector looks like
t = 1 1 1 1 1 3.5 4.5 8 8 8 8 8

which is not uniform anymore at the ends, whereas the interpolation points are. The two interior knots are averages of the interior interpolation points which seems to be a common approach.
That said, is it not common to define uniform knot vectors? Or is it even not possible, because of certain conditions?
